# Executing remote bat located on the remote computer

Tags: cmd

I need to execute a bat file located on several remote computers from my administration computer.

When I run it on the different remote computers I have no problem executing it.

When i run a "call myRemoteBat" from my local computer on all the remote ones my script doesn't run properly, raising for example the issue "foo not recongnized as an internal command"

Is there a way in the "call" command to execute using all the remote variables data?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, Luc De Maria. To see how SO works and how to ask questions, use the help information at https://stackoverflow.com/help We will need to see what is inside `myRemoteBat` in order to be able to help. Questions without code go to https://superuser.com/

Comment: Maybe [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) ist what you need.